# List of meanings for google analytics __utm cookie

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google analytics Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726994/google-analytics-cookies)

I would like to decode the information the google cookies have stored on my computer. Does anyone know a of a list matching __utm* cookies to their meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:
[http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/from-_*utma-to-*_utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html](http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/from-__utma-to-__utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html)

Comment: Wow, you found it in 2 minutes. Perhaps you should have looked before asking the question.

Comment: I did, though obviously not thoroughly enough